# Quando uso a anotação @Transactional as variáveis Autowired ficam null

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Quando uso a anotação `@Transactional` em um método anotado com `@RequestMapping` todas as variáveis anotadas com `@Autowired` estão ficando `null`.

Alguém já passou por isso? Poderiam me dar algum rumo para tentar resolver o problema?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/system/charging-values")
public class AdminSystemChargingValuesController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private ChargingValuesDao valueDao;

    @Autowired
    private MessagesHtmlsAndToasts messagesHtmlsAndToasts;

    @Autowired
    private ChargingValuesValidation changingValidation;



    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView page(ChargingValuesForm chargingValuesForm) {
        return loadPage(chargingValuesForm);
    }

    private ModelAndView loadPage(ChargingValuesForm chargingValuesForm){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(PagesLocationsAdmin.getPageSystemChargingValuesUrl().toModelAndViewPath());
        ChargingValues value = valueDao.searchActiveValue();
        if(value != null)
            chargingValuesForm = new ChargingValuesForm(value);
        modelAndView.addObject("chargingValuesForm", chargingValuesForm);
        return modelAndView;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("chargingValuesForm") ChargingValuesForm chargingValuesForm, BindingResult result,  
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(PagesLocationsAdmin.getPageSystemChargingValuesUrl().toModelAndViewPath());
        changingValidation.validate(chargingValuesForm, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            messagesHtmlsAndToasts.init(context, redirectAttributes, request, modelAndView);
            modelAndView.addObject("chargingValuesForm", chargingValuesForm);
            return modelAndView;
        }
        saveChargingValues(chargingValuesForm, modelAndView);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    private void saveChargingValues(ChargingValuesForm chargingValuesForm, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        //disable the last register active on DB
        ChargingValues value = valueDao.searchActiveValue();
        if(value != null) {
            value.setDateTimeInactivated(Calendar.getInstance());
            valueDao.update(value);
        }
        value = null;

        //Create new ChargingValues on DB
        value = new ChargingValues();       
        value.setMinPricDogWalking(chargingValuesForm.getMinPricDogWalking());  
        value.setMinPricPetGrooming(chargingValuesForm.getMinPricPetGrooming());
        value.setMinPricDogBoarding(chargingValuesForm.getMinPricDogBoarding());        
        value.setMinPricPetSitting(chargingValuesForm.getMinPricPetSitting());
        value.setPercDogWalking(chargingValuesForm.getPercDogWalking());
        value.setPercPetGrooming(chargingValuesForm.getPercPetGrooming());
        value.setPercDogBoarding(chargingValuesForm.getPercDogBoarding());
        value.setPercPetSitting(chargingValuesForm.getPercPetSitting());        
        valueDao.insert(value);
        messagesHtmlsAndToasts.toHtmlMessages(MessageType.SUCCESS, Arrays.asList("form.submit.success"));

        chargingValuesForm = new ChargingValuesForm(value);
        modelAndView.addObject("chargingValuesForm", chargingValuesForm);
    }

}
```

Comment: No seu arquivo `application.properties`, tente adicionar esta propriedade e veja se funciona: `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false`.

Comment: tudo bem hkotsubo, eu tentei aqui e não funcionou :/

Answer (score 0):

resolvido!!!

Esse é o erro

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
private
```